# Should punctuation be removed from Rasa NLU training data?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, rasa-nlu, punctuation, rasa

In the NLU training data, should punctuation (commas, apostrophes, question marks, uppercase letters, etc.) on utterances for the intents be left as is, removed, or does it matter at all?

Comment: you should remove special chars from questions. `. ? ,` etc

Answer (score 0):

The training data can be left with punctuation and the `WhitespaceTokenizer` ([documentation link](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#whitespacetokenizer)) will clean it up. Not all punctuations are cleaned up though! You can see the regex used in the tokenizer on [Github](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/rasa/nlu/tokenizers/whitespace_tokenizer.py#L35).

So for your mentioned punctuation like commas, apostrophes, question marks, etc. you can leave it there and the tokenizer will handle it.